# Configure multiple content stores in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I followed the step given in below link to configure multiple content stores in Alfresco 5.0.d.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/store-config-fullexample.html

Alfresco instance is not able to start and gives the exeption,

Cannot resolve reference to bean 'storeSelectorContentStore' while setting bean property 'store';

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'storeSelectorContentStore' defined in file [/opt/alfresco-5.0.d/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/content-store-selector-context.xml]:

I also tried the method stated in below link,
https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5156-content-store-configuration

This gives a different error, alfresco dir root not defined even though it's defined in the properties file.

Comment: please add the messages that you get (error) it will help to understand the problem

Comment: Also show the content of content-store-selector-context.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcus is right about this being an Enterprise only feature, but you could develop your own. It shouldn't be too much of a hassle.

Also, have you tried using this extension, I suspect it has everything you need and is maintained by a well know Alfresco contributor?

https://github.com/Acosix/alfresco-simple-content-stores

Answer (score 1):

This is an enterprise only feature. This is why you are getting this error on Community.